# Cálculo de soma de moeda

Tags: c#

Preciso de uma ajuda para fazer um calculo na verdade uma soma por moeda, como mostro na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

segue meu código.

```
private void ListaGrid()
    {
        conex.Open();
        string strSQL = @"SELECT DISTINCT
                        SY.YF_DESC_SI                               AS [TIPO MOEDA],
                        RTRIM(SC.C7_PRODUTO) + ' - ' + SC.C7_DESCRI AS PRODUTO,
                   SUM(SC.C7_QUANT)                            AS QTDA, 
                   SUM(SC.C7_TOTAL * SC.C7_TXMOEDA)            AS TOTAL,
                   SUM(SC.C7_TOTAL)                            AS [TOTAL MOEDA]
               FROM  SC7010 AS SC
          INNER JOIN SM2010 AS SM WITH (NOLOCK) ON SM.M2_DATA = SC.C7_EMISSAO
          INNER JOIN SA2010 AS SA WITH (NOLOCK) ON SA.A2_COD = SC.C7_FORNECE
               INNER JOIN SYF010 AS SY WITH (NOLOCK) ON SY.YF_MOEFAT = SC.C7_MOEDA
               WHERE SC.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*' 
               AND SC.C7_EMISSAO BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, '" + txtDtInicial.Text + "', 103) AND CONVERT(datetime,'" + txtDtFinal.Text + "', 103) AND SA.A2_COD = '" + txtCodFornec.Text + "' GROUP BY SC.C7_PRODUTO, SC.C7_DESCRI, SY.YF_DESC_SI ORDER BY RTRIM(SC.C7_PRODUTO) + ' - ' + SC.C7_DESCRI";

        comando = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conex);

        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter dados = new SqlDataAdapter(comando);
            DataTable dtLista = new DataTable();
            dados.Fill(dtLista);

            DGW_PedComprasPic.DataSource = dtLista;
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Não existem dados a serem encontrados");
        }

        double QTDA = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow rowKG in DGW_PedComprasPic.Rows)
        {
            QTDA += Convert.ToDouble(rowKG.Cells["QTDA"].Value);
        }
        txtProdkg.Text = Convert.ToString(QTDA);
        txtProdkg.Text = QTDA.ToString("N2");

        double TotalReal = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow rowR in DGW_PedComprasPic.Rows)
        {
            TotalReal += Convert.ToDouble(rowR.Cells["TOTAL"].Value);
        }
        txtReal.Text = Convert.ToString(TotalReal);
        txtReal.Text = TotalReal.ToString("C");

        //    double TotalDolar = 0;
        //    foreach (DataGridViewRow rowD in DGW_PedComprasPic.Rows)
        //    {
        //        TotalDolar += Convert.ToDouble(rowD.Cells["TOTAL MOEDA"].Value);
        //    }
        //    txtDolar.Text = Convert.ToString(TotalDolar);
        //    txtDolar.Text = "$ " + TotalDolar.ToString("N2");
        //    double TotalEuro = 0;
        //    foreach (DataGridViewRow rowE in DGW_PedComprasPic.Rows)
        //    {
        //        TotalEuro += Convert.ToDouble(rowE.Cells["TOTAL MOEDA"].Value);
        //    }
        //    txtEuro.Text = Convert.ToString(TotalEuro);
        //    txtEuro.Text = "€ " + TotalEuro.ToString("N2");

        //conex.Close();
    }
```

Comment: E qual é a ajuda que você precisa?

Comment: Preciso verificar na coluna TIPO DE MOEDA no datagrid, e somar. EX. tenho 4 linhad com moeda EURO, preciso somar o valor que esta na coluna TOTAL MOEDA de tudo que for EURO e mostra a coma o txtbox acima que esta com o nome Total €€

Comment: você tem 2 caminhos, fazer via SQL e retornar os dados já agrupados..utilizando computer by, ou sub-consultas, ou stored procedures ou escutar o GridView1_RowDataBound assim que os valores forem preenchidos na coluna vc vá somando.

Comment: Sim mas preciso somar por tipo de moeda, como faço isso direto no datagridview

Comment: if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
var dr = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
if dr[0].Tostring() =="euro"{ //soma

Comment: coloquei um exemplo básico pra asp.net e pra windows.form

Comment: Ainda não deu certo aqui. não sei se estou conseguindo me explicar direto, preciso verificar a coluna TIPO DE MOEDA, nessa coluna tenho linhas com dois TIPOS DE MOEDAS "EURO" e "DOLAR DOS EUA" agora preciso verificar o valor de cada linha na coluna TOTAL MOEDA, feito isso preciso somar a moeda EURO, e também somar o valora da moeda DOLAR DOS EUA, mas separadamente mostrando em um txtbox o total em valor da moeda EURO eo total em valora da moeda DOLAR DOS EUA.

Answer (score 1):

Você tem 2 caminhos.

- Fazer através do SQL (Stored procedure, ou computer by, etc) e já retornar os dados prontos.
- Ou através da propriedade GridView1_RowDataBound (ASP.NET) se for Windows.Form dataGridView1_CellFormatting ou dataGridView1_RowsAdded

*Exemplo de como manipular o RowDataBound*

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {//tem dados

     var dr = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
     if(dr[0].ToString()=="Euro")
     {
        //somaEuro += Convert.ToDecimal(dr[3]);
     }
    }
}
```

*exemplo de dataGridView1_CellFormatting*

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {

}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192961/cell-formatting-in-datagridview-on-databindingcomplete

---

Mais informações:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx